# CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE with partial debug symbols

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm trying to generate a dbgsym package alongside my regular debian package from CPack. I am using the `CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE` option for this. This works as long as either *everything* in my project contains debug symbols, or I generate separate packages from different components, in which case dbgsym packages are generated for those components containing debug symbols.

I would like, however, to generate a single package, containing all components, including those which are already stripped (they're closed-source libraries). In this case, CPack simply refuses to generate a dbgsym package.

How can I convince CPack that it's OK to generate a dbgsym package containing only those symbols that are available?